# Page Templates and User Groups - Liferay

Tags: templates, liferay, liferay-6, usergroups

I'm in trouble.

Following the **LF 6.0-Administrator-Guide** we can read inside the section User Groups and Page Templates at point Composing A Page Out of Several User Groups, page 86:

*If two or more pages of different user groups have the same name, they will be combined into a single page when they are copied to a user's personal pages set.*

For example, that means:

*If the administrator creates a page template with the same name (e.g. You are a Student ) in a Students group and puts in it a portlet, that page would be combined with the You are a Student page that's in the Teachers group, and the resulting page would contain the portlets configured for both User Groups.*

Ok, my question is: should I do anything else to make it work? I follow the steps of the Administration Guide, and I can only see that my user has 2 pages with the same name, and not a page with both pages combined.

Any ideas about that? Do you know if that's a bug at liferay 6.1?? Or if it's because I use liferay 6.1 instead of 6.0?

Comment: Have you a link to LF 6.0-Administrator-Guide?

Comment: @Mark: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/using-the-control-pan-4, search for this string in the page: "Composing A Page Out of Several User Groups"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know in Liferay 6.1 you can created pages only for Sites and not for Organizations and User-Groups as was the case in Liferay 6.0.

Still for more information you can read Liferay 6.1 Admin guide's section on [**Managing Users, User Groups, Organizations, Sites, Teams, and Roles**](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/managing-users-user-groups-organizations-sites-teams-and-roles), You can read about the **Sites** and **User groups** section in this which will I guess explain your question.

Comment: Yes, here's the concret tip:

Previous to Liferay 6.1, pages from different user groups could be combined on users' personal sites by using a naming convention. Liferay 6.1 simplifies the way user groups' sites work by disallowing page combination. Set the property user.groups.copy.layouts.to.user.personal.site to true if you depend on that functionality.